# Calculate empty labeled boxes in labeled boxes-balls problem

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, balls-in-bins

The problem is to count the number of times that K boxes are empty when *n* labeled balls are distributed into *m* labeled boxes. So, if we have n balls and m boxes, we have $m^{n}$ possibilities. I would like to count the number of times that *box 1* **and/or** *box 2* for example are empty.

For example, how many times box 1 or box 4 (*or both*) are empty when we distribute 10 balls between 10 boxes?. There are $10^{10}$ possibilities. How can it be calculated?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please read tag descriptions carefully before applying them.  This question has nothing whatsoever to do with the calculus of variations.

Comment: Well, if box $1$ is empty, all the balls have been distributed to the other $9$ boxes ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: To ensure that some boxes are empty the balls have to be distributed between the remaining boxes.

For example:

The number of ways to distribute 10 balls so that the box 1 is empty is $9^{10}$.

The number of ways to distribute 10 balls so that the boxes 1 and 4 are empty is $8^{10}$.

Keep in mind that the above numbers count also the events with some other boxes being empty.